# How to increase or decrease an Android Text-views size based on it's contents?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

Width + wrap_content works fine with other single line TextViews within my layout. However my multiline TextViews will neither shrink or grow to adapt to the numbers within it. Ideally I would like the view to wrap both it's height and width to fit the content within it.

The TextViews 1-10 (the textViews positioned at the top of each button) are single lined and work just as I want them to. They expand and shrink based on their size (wrap to content works as it should).

The TextViews 11-20 are fixed in size and will not shrink or expand despite having identical code other than being multilined. (they use \n within their strings). They should consist of two numbers between 0 and 100 positioned vertically.

***Interface***

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton5" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton5" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView7" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton7" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView9" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton9" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView10" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton10" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton10" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7" android:text="0/0/0" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5" android:text="0/0/0" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0/0/0" android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1" android:text="0/0/0" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"></TextView>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView11" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nextHandButton" android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView12" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_above="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView13" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView12" android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView14" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton4"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView15" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView5" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton5" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView16" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton6" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextHandButton"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView17" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton7" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6" android:layout_marginRight="50dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView18" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView8" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton8" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView7" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView17" android:maxLines="2"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView19" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton9" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton9" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView18"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView20" android:visibility="invisible" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton10" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView16" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLines="2"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please put your whole xml layout under which you are using this TextView So we can help you more precise.

Comment: textView 1-10 work just as I want them to. They are single lined and expand or shrink horizontally depending on the size of the numbers within them.
textView 11-20 will not expand or shrink to fit the numbers within them. They're size is fixed and I don't want it to be. They are identical in every way except they are multilined using \n strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened here was a consequence of using eclipses drag and drop graphical layout with androids relative layout rather than typing the relative constraints myself. There were unecessary constraints in place such as:

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView18"
```

The above constraint would stop the view from expanding to the right. These constraints were stopping the width or height wrap content properties from taking effect. If your facing a similar problem have a good look through your code for relative layout constraints that may be overriding your Views ability to expand or shrink in the direction you want it to.